# Uniqueness of integral curves.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, differential-topology

Suppose we have a smooth compact manifold $M$ with boundary and a vector field $X$ on $M$. The maximal integral curves on $M$ are unique and hence their images give a partition of $M$.

Let $p\in M$ be a point in $M$, such that $X(p)=0$. The constant curve at $p$ fulfills the conditions on an integral curve and hence it is the unique maximal integral curve starting at $p$. This shows that the zero set of the vector field is in one-to-one correspondence to the constant maximal integral curves, right?

Now come my confusion: For sure there are vector fields $X$ with isolated zero-points, such that some inetgral curves of a point non zero $q$ runs in the direction of a zero point $p$. (Think of a gradient-like vector field for a morse function.) By the thoughts above, this curve cannot run into $p$, as the integral curve of the zero point is constant and unique, so my conclusion is, that the curve going to the $p$ has to stop right before $p$. But as $M$ is compact, integral curves are defined on the whole real line, so this tastes like a contradiction.

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prototypical example for this situation is something like the vector field $-x \partial_x$ on a one-dimensional manifold. This has a zero at $x=0$, and indeed the flow at $x=0$ is constant; but this does not stop the flow starting at any other point from being maximally defined.

Your mistake is in confusing "defined on all of $\mathbb R$" with a statement about the image of the curve. In my example above, the integral curve starting at $x_0$ is simply $x(t) = x_0 e^{-t}$, which is defined on all of $\mathbb R$, but never hits $0$ - it just asymptotically approaches it. The fact that the image of the curve could be extended (i.e. the curve could be extended after a reparametrization) does *not* mean that the curve itself is not maximally defined.

Comment: Thank you. Seems like I had fundamentally the wrong picture about this situation in my head. So having a maximal integral curve, which is defined on $\mathbb{R}$ doesn't mean it leaves all compact subsets of the manifold? I think I misunderstood the escape lemma...

Comment: @Tina: the escape lemma applies exactly when the maximal integral curve is defined on something *smaller* than $\mathbb R$.  I think the key point to keep in mind is that the vector field controls not only the direction of the integral curves, but their velocities too; and by choosing the magnitude of the field appropriately, we can get situations where the integral curves stay bounded while the curve time goes to infinity (like my example), and vice versa situations where the integral curves escape to infinity in finite time (e.g. $x^2 \partial_x$).